# How do I set the uncomment shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio

For previous versions of Visual Studio --- Tools => Options => Keyboard => Edit.UncommentSelection => Ctr+Shift+/.  This removes the // in front of comments.

For Visual Studio 2019, Ctr+Shift+/ places /**/ around that line.

Note that setting Edit.CommentSelection to Ctrl+/ works fine for all versions of VS (places // in front of comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the default Keyboard shortcut *(Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U)* for uncommenting snippets of code, or assign a new shortcut to replace the default option with keys of your choice, as shown below:

[image: Custom Keyboard shorcut for uncommenting code in VS2019]

Reference: [Customize a keyboard shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#customize-a-keyboard-shortcut)